# Prevent pandas from changing int to float/date?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to merge a series of xlsx files into one, which works fine.
However, when I read a file, columns containing ints are transformed into floats (or dates?) when I merge and output them to csv. I have tried to visualize this in the picture. I have seen some solutions to this where dtype is used to "force" specific columns into int format. However, I do not always know the index nor the title of the column, so i need a more scalable solution.

Anyone with some thoughts on this?

Thank you in advance

[image: Visualisation of problem]

```html
#specify folder with xlsx-files
xlsFolder = "{}/system".format(directory)
dfMaster = pd.DataFrame()

#make a list of all xlsx-files in folder
xlsFolderContent = os.listdir(xlsFolder)
xlsFolderList = []
for file in xlsFolderContent:
    if file[-5:] == ".xlsx":
        xlsFolderList.append(file)

for xlsx in xlsFolderList:
    print(xlsx)
    xl = pd.ExcelFile("{}/{}".format(xlsFolder, xlsx))
    
    for sheet in xl.sheet_names:
        if "_Errors" in sheet:
            print(sheet)
            dfSheet = xl.parse(sheet)
            dfSheet.fillna(0, inplace=True)
            dfMaster = dfMaster.append(dfSheet)
            print("len of dfMaster:", len(dfMaster))


dfMaster.to_csv("{}/dfMaster.csv".format(xlsFolder),sep=";")
```

Data sample:
[image: Data sample]

Comment: please provide a sample of the data, you likely have missing values. Try to use `convert_dtypes`

Comment: Added a screenshot of the data. I do have missing values, which I mitigate using fillna(0) in the code.

Comment: you need to provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `dtype='object'` as parameter of `pd.read_csv` or (`ExcelFile.parse`) to prevent Pandas to infer the data type of each column. You can also simplify your code using `pathlib`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

directory = pathlib.Path('your_path_directory')
xlsFolder = directory / 'system'

data = []
for xlsFile in xlsFolder.glob('*.xlsx'):
    sheets = pd.read_excel(xlsFile, sheet_name=None, dtype='object')
    for sheetname, df in sheets.items():
        if '_Errors' in sheetname:
            data.append(df.fillna('0'))

pd.concat(data).to_csv(xlsxFolder / dfMaster.csv, sep=';')
```